# Group by and only first row should have value in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame :

```
df <- data.frame (f1  = c("A1000", "A1000","A1000", "A1000","A1000"),
                   f2 = c("1200", "1200","1200", "1300","1300"),
                  f3 = c("1300", "1400","1500", "1000","2000"),
                  f4 =c("M100","M100","M100","B2300","B2300"),
                  f5=c("D100","D100","D100","G4500","G4500")
)
```

I would like to reformat it with the following output
If the value in f1,f2 are same then value at the f4 and f5 should appear only at first row. Rest of the values of f4 and f5 should become blank.

```
f1  f2 f3 f4 f5  
A1000 1200 1300 M100 D100  
A1000 1200 1400  
A1000 1200 1500  
A1000 1300 1000 B2300 G4500   
A1000 1300 1000
```

Any help is  highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `dplyr` answer

```
df %>% group_by(f1, f2) %>% 
  mutate(f4 = ifelse(row_number() != 1, NA, f4),
         f5 = ifelse(row_number() != 1, NA, f5))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   f1, f2 [2]
  f1    f2    f3    f4    f5   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A1000 1200  1300  M100  D100 
2 A1000 1200  1400  NA    NA   
3 A1000 1200  1500  NA    NA   
4 A1000 1300  1000  B2300 G4500
5 A1000 1300  2000  NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, it is a bit of a hack solution but basically I'm using `paste` and `duplicated` to find the first instance of each `f1`, `f2` pair.

I have used `NA` but you can swap that for `""` in each `ifelse` if you want blank characters

```
df <- data.frame (f1  = c("A1000", "A1000","A1000", "A1000","A1000"),
                  f2 = c("1200", "1200","1200", "1300","1300"),
                  f3 = c("1300", "1400","1500", "1000","2000"),
                  f4 =c("M100","M100","M100","B2300","B2300"),
                  f5=c("D100","D100","D100","G4500","G4500")
)

df$f4 <- ifelse(!duplicated(paste(df$f1,df$f2)), df$f4,NA)
df$f5 <- ifelse(!duplicated(paste(df$f1,df$f2)), df$f5,NA)
```

output:

```
     f1   f2   f3    f4    f5
1 A1000 1200 1300  M100  D100
2 A1000 1200 1400  <NA>  <NA>
3 A1000 1200 1500  <NA>  <NA>
4 A1000 1300 1000 B2300 G4500
5 A1000 1300 2000  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: If you have more columns to deal with you can wrap the `ifelse` statement in an `apply` function. e.g. `df[,c('f4','f5')] <- apply(df[,c('f4','f5')],2, function(i) 
  ifelse(!duplicated(paste(df$f1,df$f2)), i,NA)
  )`

Answer (score 1):

With `Base R`,

```
 group <- paste0(df$f1,df$f2)
    df[setdiff(1:nrow(df),match(unique(group),group)),c("f4","f5")] <- NA
    
    df
```

gives,

```
     f1   f2   f3    f4    f5
1 A1000 1200 1300  M100  D100
2 A1000 1200 1400  <NA>  <NA>
3 A1000 1200 1500  <NA>  <NA>
4 A1000 1300 1000 B2300 G4500
5 A1000 1300 2000  <NA>  <NA>
>
```